# ansible jinja2 template file creation based on input values

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template, dynamic-content

i want to create a file application.properties file and copy it over to specific location. im using template module for same. but i want to create content of the file based on comma separated input ip addresses count/values

the content of the file should is below.

conf_pg_hba_replication.connection=host    replication     oracle        {{IP1}}/32      trust\nhost     replication     oracle      {{IP2}}/32      trust\nhost     replication     oracle      {{IP3}}/32.............

so i want my file to be created with dynamic content based on comma separated input ip address value.

if my input ip value is 127.0.0.1,123.123.123.123
file content should be

conf_pg_hba_replication.connection=host    replication     oracle        127.0.0.1/32      trust\nhost     replication     oracle      123.123.123.123/32      trust

so likewise i need to create contents of file.

please help me on this.

```
---
- name: pp
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - name: pp
     template:
      src: pp.j2
      dest: pp.properties
      newline_sequence: \n

-bash-4.2$ cat pp.j2
conf_pg_hba_replication.connection=host    replication     oracle       {{slave_ip}}/32      trust
```

i pass ips list through a variable to ansible playbook like below
ansible-playbook postgres.yml -e "ips_list=ip1,ip2,ip3"

Comment: How do you load the list of ips ?

Comment: i pass it through a variable to ansible playbook, ansible-playbook postgres.yml -e "ips_list=ip1,ip2,ip3"

Comment: This should not be a comment but an edit to your question. While you are at it, you can also format your first code block correctly to make it more readable.

Comment: thanks, edited the question. also i'vent started with coding yet and need inputs to write jinja2 template to achive.

Comment: Please format your code correctly, either in blocks or inline. You have format buttons on top of the editor window and help on the right side of the screen. Also, note that SO tend to function the other way arround: you write code and show what you have done and ask questions about specific problems you are facing while trying to put a solution in place. It's quite short and easy here so I still decided to answer. But keep this in mind for your future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a coma separated ip list as an extra var on the ansible command line.

To acheive your requirement you need to:

1. transform the string containing the coma separated list to a real list with the `split` function.
2. loop over you list in your template to output the result.

This can actually be done in a single task. Given the following `templates/pp.j2`...

```
{% for slave_ip in ip_list %}
conf_pg_hba_replication.connection=host    replication     oracle        {{ slave_ip }}/32      trust
{% endfor %}
```

and the following playbook...

```yaml
---
- name: template our pp file
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: pp
      template:
        src: pp.j2
        dest: pp.properties
      vars:
        ip_list: "{{ ip_list_raw.split(',') }}"
```

that you call like this...

```sh
ansible-playbook test.yml -e "ip_list_raw=127.0.0.1,1.2.3.4,5.6.7.8"
```

you get the following result

```
$ cat pp.properties 
conf_pg_hba_replication.connection=host    replication     oracle        127.0.0.1/32      trust
conf_pg_hba_replication.connection=host    replication     oracle        1.2.3.4/32      trust
conf_pg_hba_replication.connection=host    replication     oracle        5.6.7.8/32      trust
```

---

Note that you can also drop the vars declaration with the `split` in the template task by passing directly the list of ips as a json array on the command line

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -e '{"ip_list":["127.0.0.1","1.2.3.4","5.6.7.8"]}'
```

Or even load them from an external yaml file e.g. `my_ip_list.yml`

```yaml
---
ip_list:
  - 127.0.0.1
  - 1.2.3.4
  - 5.6.7.8
```

like this:

```yaml
ansible-playbook test.yml -e @my_ip_list.yml'
```

Comment: thanks alot, my output properties file should be in below format   `conf_pg_hba_replication.connection=host    replication     oracle        127.0.0.1/32      trust
\nhost    replication     oracle        1.2.3.4/32      trust\nhost    replication     oracle        5.6.7.8/32      trust `

Comment: i tried below and able to get somehow and i m looking for output in one line and \n as a separator for each entry  `conf_pg_hba_replication.connection={% for slave_ip in ip_list %}
host    replication     oracle        {{ slave_ip }}/32      trust
{% endfor %}`

Comment: \n is shown as a normal line break when you look at the file....

Comment: below is the output below is the output `conf_pg_hba_replication.connection=host    replication     oracle        127.0.0.1/32      trust
host    replication     oracle        1.2.3.4/32      trust
host    replication     oracle        5.6.7.8/32      trust
`

Comment: cool, so is it ok if i can ignore the \n in file and proceed with above changes ? assuming both files are same if we keep \n in single line, and remove \n and have different rows.